# Javascript return in window.onbeforeunload doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

I am writing a piece of Javascript that stops a timer when it is running (active == 1) and the window is closed, a link is clicked, ...

I decided to use a window.onbeforeunload function that works great on IE and FF but doesn't on Chrome.

When I close the window when having a running timer in Chrome, I do get the warning that I'm leaving the page with "false" displayed above that.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function SetEndTimeOnClose(lngPersonID,lngToDoID){
if(active == 1){
    var answer = confirm("Wil je de tijd stoppen?");
    if (answer){        
        try{
            StopStopwatch();
            SetEndTime(lngPersonID,lngToDoID);
        }
        catch(err){
        };
        return true;    
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return SetEndTimeOnClose(<%=lngOpenPersonID%>,<%=lngToDoID%>);
}
```

Comment: Firefox and IE apparently allow a `confirm()` call to work in a "beforeunload" handler, but I think Chrome is doing the right thing here. A `confirm()` within the handler is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/PQz5k/

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload), you need to return a string that will be displayed in the confirmation dialog.

Comment: There is no workaround in Chrome for this? The strange thing is that it works perfectly in IE and FF.

Comment: The strange thing is that Mozilla FF behaves differently than it is described on Mozilla's Developer Network. Did you try `return "Wil je de tijd stoppen?";` from the handler and calling `StopStopwatch();             SetEndTime(lngPersonID,lngToDoID);` from the `unload` event handler?